# How to use signed or unsigned integer for bit mapping in C?

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, bitmap, out-of-memory

I want to reset the 31st bit (last bit, 0 to 31 range) of int32_t, only this case seems to fail.
i.e., Output failed for the case when 'i' is 31, it's returning -1. What is the error and how do I resolve this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void Release(int ResetBit, int32_t *Val)
{
    int32_t testBit = 1; /* XoR Bit */

    if (ResetBit >= 0 && ResetBit < 32)
    {
        testBit = (testBit << ResetBit);
        *Val ^= testBit;
    }
    else
    {
        perror("Max range is 0-31 only, failed! ");
        //exit(1);
    }  
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++)
    {
        int32_t MaxValue = 2147483647;
        Release(i, &MaxValue);
        printf("MaxValue = %d NodeID = % d\n", MaxValue, i);
        count++;
   }
    printf("%d", count);
    return 0;
}
```

Output for the case i = 31 is:

MaxValue = -1 NodeID =  31

Comment: Well, don't use signed integers for this (shifting signed integers may resolve in undefined behavior). Use unsigned, i.e. `uint32_t`. Besides that it's not fully clear what you mean by `Release` - is it "set to zero" or is it "toggle the bit"?

Comment: I want "set to zero" a particular bit (in the range 0-31). To set a particular bit to zero, I am passing 'i' as a bit position. Eg: to set 5th bit to zero, i = 4.

Comment: @4386427 I tried with u_int32_t, it gives the same error

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4009885/arithmetic-bit-shift-on-a-signed-integer#:~:text=As%20of%20c%2B%2B20,b%20%2C%20rounded%20down%20(ie.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the **result**, it is your **signed value with all bits set**. If you want to see unsigned use `unsigned` **and** print with `%u`.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Except `testBit = (testBit << 31);` relies on UB to get that result. So in theory it could print anything. In practice there's likely some non-standard extension guaranteeing deterministic behavior for this case.

Comment: @Lundin in theory yes, but in practice, the compilers OP is likely to use this would actually have it defined (GCC, Clang, MSVC), and the problem is that OP expected to see a <very large number> instead of -1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all: **Don't use signed integers for bitmaps.** Always use **unsigned**. The reason for that is that bit shifting on signed integers may result in undefined behavior while shifting unsigned integers are always safe.

Secondly: You are using XOR in the `Release` function. XOR with `testBit`  will not clear a bit. XOR will toggle the bit value, i.e. 1 becomes 0 and 0 becomes 1. Instead you want: `*Val &= ~testBit;` It works like:

```
If testBit is    0000.0000.0000.0000.0000.0000.0000.1000
then ~testbit is 1111.1111.1111.1111.1111.1111.1111.0111
then *Val &= ... will clear bit number 3 and keep all other unchanged 
as `&` is a bitwise AND operation.
```

When using unsigned remember to change the `printf` to print an unsigned instead of using `%d`, i.e. like `printf("%" PRIu32 "\n", uint32t_variable);`.

**EDIT**

What went wrong with the XOR?

Let's assume that you are using `uint32_t` and XOR, then this will happen:

Your input is

```
0111.1111.1111.1111.1111.1111.1111.1111
```

and you XOR with

```
1000.0000.0000.0000.0000.0000.0000.0000
```

which toggles bit 31 resulting in

```
1111.1111.1111.1111.1111.1111.1111.1111
```

The function was supposed to clear bit 31 but it didn't. XOR is just not the correct operator for that.

Comment: Even though XOR  toggles, isn't it achieving the required task, ie., *Var ^= testBit; ? can you elaborate on this?

Comment: ***`Don't use signed integers for bitmaps.`*** it actually does not matter in this case. The mask matters

Comment: @P__J__ From N1570 6.3.1.3 " ...  the new type is signed and the value cannot be represented in it; either the
result is implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal is raised."

Comment: It does not apply here

Comment: @P__J__ hmm... so what applies instead?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need an actual signed type, use `uint32_t` and all problems will go away. The problem with using bitwise operators on signed types is various forms of poorly-defined behavior.

For example, left-shifting something into the sign bit of a `int32_t` leads to undefined behavior, meaning a potential bug in case your compiler doesn't cover that case with a non-standard extension. Similarly, right-shifting a negative number can either lead to arithmetic or logic shift, the C standard doesn't specify which one, but allows both forms.

That being said, if you simply wish to set/clear bit 31 of an `int32_t`, it's well-defined to do so like this:

```
int32_t i32 = ...;
i32 |= 1u << 31;    // set MSB
i32 &= ~(1u << 31); // clear MSB
i32 ^= 1u << 31;    // toggle MSB
```

Where the `u` is ensuring unsigned arithmetic.

Comment: Isn't this conflicting with https://stackoverflow.com/a/9498852/4386427

Comment: @4386427 Why would it? That post is about a different topic of implicit promotion/conversion.

Comment: Isn't there an unsigned to signed conversion here? And wouldn't that fall into #3 of the last part of the linked answer?

Comment: @4386427 Yes there is a lvalue conversion from signed to unsigned and it's implementation-defined - mostly because C allows exotic signedness formats. In practice, the impl.-defined part is "this computer uses 2's complement", but otherwise behaves deterministically on every compiler I've ever used. Meaning that the unsigned number gets converted to the raw binary equivalent in 2's complement.

Answer (score 1):

Use the correct bitwise operation. to reset bit use `&`

```
int32_t ResetBit(int bit, int32_t *val)
{
    uint32_t mask = ~(1UL << bit);

    *val &= mask;
    return *val;
}
```

and usage:

```
void printnitd(int32_t val)
{
    for(uint32_t mask = 1UL << 31; mask; mask >>= 1)
    {
        printf("%c",  (val & mask) ? '1' : '0');
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    for(int bit = 0; bit < 32; bit++)
    {
        int32_t a = -1;
        printf("bit %u = ", a);
        printnitd(ResetBit(bit, &a));
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```