# What is wrong with my For loops? i get warnings: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>


using namespace std;

int main() {

    vector<double> vector_double;
    vector<string> vector_string;
    ...


    while (cin >> sample_string)
        {
            ...
        }

    for(int i = 0; i <= vector_string.size(); i++)
        {
            ....
        }

    for (int i = 0; i < vector_double.size(); i++)
        ....


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The error tells you exactly what is wrong. There is exactly one comparison operation per for loop, so you can see what's being compared to which. You can see that `i` is of a signed type (you picked the type!), so that logically implies that the other expression is of an unsigned type.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I fix warnings like: "comparison between signed and unsigned"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/859943/how-can-i-fix-warnings-like-comparison-between-signed-and-unsigned)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> Why is there a warning with `-Wsign-compare` ?

As the name of the warning, and its text, imply, the issue is that you are comparing a signed and an unsigned integer. It is generally assumed that this is an accident.

In order to avoid this warning, you simply need to ensure that both operands of `<` (or any other comparison operator) are either both signed or both unsigned.

> How could I do better ?

The idiomatic way of writing a `for` loop is to initialize *both* the counter and the limit in the first statement:

```
for (std::size_t i = 0, max = vec.size(); i != max; ++i)
```

This saves recomputing `size()` at each iteration.

You could also (and probably should) use iterators instead of indices:

```
for (auto it = vec.begin(), end = vec.end(); it != end; ++it)
```

`auto` here is a shorthand for `std::vector<int>::iterator`. Iterators work for any kind of containers, whereas indices limit you to C-arrays, `deque` and `vector`.

Comment: this worked. although max() didn't work so i changed it to max. thanks

Comment: I wouldnt use the max way because - depending on your loop, the size of the vec can change, so it is safer to check every time for the actual size of the vec.

Comment: Initializing the limit first only works if the container does not change size inside the loop.  Otherwise, I would declare the limit as a `const` variable before the loop, to give the compiler additional ammunition against programmers trying to change the variable.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: unfortunately, changing the vector won't change the limit either. I prefer to declare the limit within the loop because I want scopes as tight as possible for my variables.

Comment: @bamboon: fair limitation, but I'll give you a slap on the head if you attempt it; it's too easy to screw up. There are dedicated algorithms (like `remove_if`) that are generally better suited to these tasks. And at worst, a `while` clause will generate the proper attention from the reader.

Comment: The choice of `max` as a variable name is unfortunate, since it shadows the standard function `max`. `end` has the same problem. Maybe a good substitute would be `stop`?

Comment: @MarkRansom: never been an issue for me, if the compiler complains "max" is not a function, I can always rename it.

Comment: Sure, *you'll* recognize the problem right away. What about the poor person who uses your answer to solve their problem, only to end up with another problem?

Comment: @MarkRansom: I cannot predict in advance which names will be in scope in another person's code, it's up to the user of the answer to make the necessary adaptation. What if they have a `stop` variable or function? What if `end` collides with `std::end` (C++11)? There's a thousands possible collisions (which is why I recommend NOT having `using namespace std;`).

Comment: How could I use `auto` with the index version? If I write `auto i = 0, max = vec.size()` I get an "inconsistent deduction" error as the compiler deduces `int` type for `i` and `long long unsigned int` for `max`.

Comment: @Sergio: You could use `auto i = `std::size_t(0)`, max = vec.size()`, however at that point I'd just recommend using `std::size_t i = 0, max = vec.size()`.

Comment: @MatthieuM. in c++23 you can use `auto i = 0zu` to deduce `size_t`

Answer (score 7):

It is because the .size() function from the vector class is not of type int but of type vector::size_type

Use that or `auto i = 0u` and the messages should disappear.

Comment: Using auto here won't work as the deducted type would be signed int. Using auto i=0U; works.

Answer (score 3):

You get this warning because the size of a container in C++ is an unsigned type and mixing signed/unsigned types is dangerous.

What I do normally is

```
for (int i=0,n=v.size(); i<n; i++)
    ....
```

this is in my opinion the best way to use indexes because using an unsigned type for an index (or the size of a container) is a logical mistake.

Unsigned types should be used only when you care about the bit representation and when you are going to use the modulo-(2**n) behavior on overflow. Using unsigned types just because a value is never negative is a nonsense.

A typical bug of using unsigned types for sizes or indexes is for example

```
// Draw all lines between adjacent points
for (size_t i=0; i<pts.size()-1; i++)
    drawLine(pts[i], pts[i+1]);
```

the above code is UB when the point array is empty because in C++ `0u-1` is a huge positive number.

The reason for which C++ uses an unsigned type for size of containers is because of an historical heritage from 16-bit computers (and IMO given C++ semantic with unsigned types it was the wrong choice even back then).

Answer (score 3):

`int` is signed by default - it is equivalent to writing `signed int`. The reason you get a warning is because `size()` returns a `vector::size_type` which is more than likely unsigned.

This has potential danger since `signed int` and `unsigned int` hold different ranges of values. `signed int` can hold values between `–2147483648` to `2147483647` while an `unsigned int` can hold values between `0` to `4294967295` (assuming `int` is 32 bits).

Answer (score 3):

I usually solve it like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i <= (int)vector_string.size(); i++)
```

I use the C-style cast because it's shorter and more readable than the C++ `static_cast<int>()`, and accomplishes the same thing.

There's a potential for overflow here, but only if your vector size is larger than the largest `int`, typically 2147483647. I've never in my life had a vector that large. If there's even a remote possibility of using a larger vector, one of the answers suggesting `size_type` would be more appropriate.

I don't worry about calling `size()` repeatedly in the loop, since it's likely an inline access to a member variable that introduces no overhead.

Answer (score 2):

Your variable `i` is an integer while the `size` member function of vector which returns an `Allocator::size_type` is most likely returning a `size_t`, which is almost always implemented as an unsigned int of some size.

Answer (score 2):

Make your `int i` as `size_type i`.
`std::vector::size()` will return `size_type` which is an `unsigned int` as size cannot be -ve.
The warning is obviously because you are comparing signed integer with unsigned integer.

Answer (score 2):

Answering after so many answers, but no one noted the loop end.. So, here's my full answer:

1. To remove the warning, change the `i`'s type to be `unsigned`, `auto` (for C++11), or `std::vector< your_type >::size_type`
2. Your `for` loops will seg-fault, if you use this `i` as index - you must loop from `0` to `size-1`, inclusive. So, change it to be
   `for( std::vector< your_type >::size_type i = 0; i < vector_xxx.size(); ++i )`
   (note the `<`, not `<=`; my advise is not to use `<=` with `.begin() - 1`, because you can have a 0 size vector and you *will* have issues with that :) ).
3. To make this more generic, as you're using a container and you're iterating through it, you can use `iterator`s. This will make easier future change of the container type (if you don't need the exact position as number, of course). So, I would write it like this:

---

```
for( std::vector< your_type >::iterator iter = vector_XXX.begin(); 
     iter != vector_XXX.end(); 
     ++iter )
{
    //..
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Declaring 'size_t i' for me work well.

Answer (score 0):

```
std::cout << -1U << std::endl;
std::cout << (unsigned)-1 << std::endl;
4294967295

std::cout << 1 << std::endl;
std::cout << (signed)1 << std::endl;
1

std::cout << (unsigned short)-1 << std::endl;
65535

std::cout << (signed)-1U << std::endl;
std::cout << (signed)4294967295 << std::endl;
-1
```

unsign your index variable

```
unsigned int index;
index < vecArray.size() // size() would never be negative
```

Answer (score 0):

Some answers are suggesting using `auto`, but that won't work as `int` is the default type deduced from integer literals. Pre [c++23](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b23) you have to explicitly specify the type `std::size_t` defined in [cstddef](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cstddef) header

```
for(std::size_t i = 0; i <= vector_string.size(); i++)
{
    ....
}
```

In c++23 the integral literal [zu](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal)  was added, the [motivation](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/p0330r8.html#motivation) was indeed to allow the correct type to be deduced.

```
for(auto i = 0zu; i <= vector_string.size(); i++)
{
    ....
}
```

But unfortunately no [compiler support](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support) this feature yet.