# comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare] warning

Tags: c, for-loop, comparison, warnings, unsigned

```
for ( i= 0; i < sizeof(r)/sizeof(r[0]); ++i ){ 
        r[i]= 0; 
}
```

So this is the for loop I'm having troubles with, how can I rewrite it so I don't get the warning:

```
comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
```

Comment: `int size = sizeof(r)/sizeof(r[0]);` ... `i < size` or `size_t i;`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C: how can I fix warnings like: "comparison between signed and unsigned"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/859943/c-how-can-i-fix-warnings-like-comparison-between-signed-and-unsigned)

Answer (score 6):

`sizeof()` returns an unsigned integer of type `size_t`.  So use an index of the same type.

```
size_t i;
for (i = 0; i < sizeof(r)/sizeof(r[0]); ++i) { 
  r[i] = 0; 
}
```

Recommend to *not* use `int size = sizeof(r)/sizeof(r[0]);`.  The range of `size_t` may greatly exceed the positive range of `int`.  The assignment could then lose significant bits.

`size_t` is the type best used to index array variables.  Remember, though, since it is some unsigned integer, it can not represent negative indexes.

Answer (score 2):

In your code:

```
for ( i= 0; i < sizeof(r)/sizeof(r[0]); ++i ){ 
        r[i]= 0; 
}
```

I think the "i" is declared as an int, try "**unsigned int i;**" like this:

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < sizeof(r)/sizeof(r[0]); ++i ){ 
        r[i]= 0; 
}
```

Run your code and it should remove this warning for sure.

Answer (score 0):

The warning can be suppressed by typecasting the **sizeof** operator's output
using `(int)`.

```
for ( i= 0; i < (int)(sizeof(r)/sizeof(r[0])); ++i )
{ 
        r[i]= 0; 
}
```

However, the range of `size_t` (the result type of **sizeof**) is often much higher than `int`, so the result of the cast can become negative for large objects.  Only use this technique if you are sure the result will fit in a signed integer.