# Comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I just started using OpenGL. This is my first code:

```
// OpenGL hello program
#include<iostream>
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <cstring>

void display() {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    char message[] = "Hello, world!";
    glRasterPos2d(0, 0);
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(message) / sizeof(message[0]); i++)
    {
        glutBitmapCharacter(GLUT_BITMAP_HELVETICA_12, message[i]);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitWindowSize(500, 500);
    glutCreateWindow("OpenGL hello program");
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutMainLoop();
}
```

The error I am getting is: *Warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions (line 9).*
I also tried writing a new code then to see whats causing the problem:

```
#include<iostream>
#include <cstring>

void display1() {
    char message[] = "Hello, world!";

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(message) / sizeof(message[0]); i++)
        std::cout<<message[i];
}

int main() {
    display1();
}
```

This code works perfectly fine. Why is the first code not working fine?

**EDIT:**
Following up on Cyber's annswer, I changed the loop to:

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < sizeof(message) / sizeof(message[0]); i++)
```

But the *OpenGL* code does not do the expected i.e. show "Hello, world!" message in the window. It just creates a window with "OpenGL hello program" written at the top and nothing else.

Comment: `sizeof` operator returns `size_t` which is unsigned integral type. In the for loop's conditional you are comparing the result of a division between two `sizeof`s which is an unsigned integral value with `i` that is an `int`.

Comment: Why is the second code working fine then?

Comment: The second piece of code issues the same warning.

Comment: @Cyber I mean for the first code (OpenGL), not the test code (second one)

Comment: Note that `sizeof(message)` returns the number of entries only in C++ since there `sizeof(char)==1`.

Comment: Your code is working fine, because this is a warning, not an error. The problem is that the compiler writers observed that whenever a compiler sees code like yours, there is only a 50% chance that the code behaves in the way the programmer intended. So the compiler is *warning* you that you might not have written what you intended to write. Nice guys, the compiler people, aren't they?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C: how can I fix warnings like: "comparison between signed and unsigned"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/859943/c-how-can-i-fix-warnings-like-comparison-between-signed-and-unsigned)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This line is the problem

```
for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(message) / sizeof(message[0]); i++)
```

The operator [`sizeof`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof) has the return type of [`std::size_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t) which is therefore what you should use for the type of your variable `i`. `std::size_t` is an unsigned type, so the compiler is warning you that you are comparing a signed type (`int`) to an unsigned type, because the comparison is potentially unsafe if the value of one variable is not in the representable range of in the other type.

```
for (std::size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(message) / sizeof(message[0]); ++i)
```

Or simply use a range-based for loop.

```
for (auto i : message)
{
    std::cout << i;    // i is a char from the message array
}
```

Comment: @Bosnia:  Your question seems focused on the signed/unsigned warning, which has been answered.  If you have a different question, you should probably start a new post.  If you intended to ask a different question here, you should probably correct the title and the tags and focus the text on the other issue.

Answer (score -1):

`for (int i =0,i<sizeof ....)`
That line is the problem. The `sizeof` function returns an `unsigned integer` thus causing error when compared to the `signed int`.
Try creating an `int` variable for the `sizeof` like this:

`int size=sizeof()...`

Then  replace in your line as follows:

`for (int i=0,i<size...)`