# warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions..how to solve it?

Tags: c++, integer, size, unsigned, signed

i am getting a comparison between signed and unsigned integer expression in my code:

```
    vector<long int> row;
    long n,m;
    long int pro=1;
    cin>>n;
    for(long i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        long int temp;
        for(long j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
            cin >> temp;
            row.push_back(temp);
        }
    }

    cin >> m;
    for(long i=0;i<row.size();i++)
        pro = pro * pow(row[i],m);

    long int mod = 1000000007;
    cout<< (long int)pro%mod;
```

At the line: `for(long i=0;i<row.size();i++)`

How can I fix this warning?

Comment: In case one does *not* feel like counting. `pro = pro * pow(row[i],m);` is row 27. Please mark problematic lines with comments denoting line number, such as `// line 27 HERE`. Thanks.

Comment: I'm betting that in **the real code**, `for(long i=0;i<row.size();i++)` is row 27.

Comment: @DrewDormann I'd back you on that bet, not that you need it.

Comment: Why are you using _both_ `long` and `long int`? They're the same type.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C: how can I fix warnings like: "comparison between signed and unsigned"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/859943/c-how-can-i-fix-warnings-like-comparison-between-signed-and-unsigned)

Comment: did you ever copy the warning and google it? results will come immediately and there are tons of duplicates on SO

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`std::vector::size`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/size) returns a value of `size_type`, which is [Unsigned integral type (usually `std::size_t`)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector#Member_types).

Your loop count variable is of type `long` which is a *signed* type. So in the loop condition you are comparing a signed and an unsigned type.

The solution is simple: Use `std::vector<long int>::size_type` (or maybe even `size_t`) instead of `long`.

Comment: Or `decltype(row)::size_type` so you don't have to change it if the element type of `row` happened to change.

Answer (score 2):

[`vector::size`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/size) returns a `size_type` which is an unsigned integral value.

You can fix this one of two ways:

1. Use an unsigned iterator in your `for`-loop: `for(auto i = 0U; i < row.size(); ++i)`
2. Cast the return of `vector::size` to a signed integer: `for(auto i = 0; i < static_cast<int>(row.size()); ++i)`

Answer (score 0):

C++ has a thing called the [**range-based `for` loop**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for), which relieves you from the burden of dealing with index variables. It also solves your mismatched signedness problem:

```
for(long r : row)
    pro = pro * pow(r,m);
```

Just use it.