# comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions?

Tags: c++

currently compiling my set.cpp file(we had to make that file based on the set.h file and test_set.cpp) Using a g++ compiler, and I keep running into these warnings:

```
set.cpp: In member function âvoid set::remove(const set::value_type&)â:
set.cpp:30: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions
set.cpp: In member function âbool set::contains(const set::value_type&) constâ:
set.cpp:50: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions
set.cpp: In function âset set_union(const set&, const set&)â:
set.cpp:65: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions
set.cpp: In function âset set_intersection(const set&, const set&)â:
set.cpp:76: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions
set.cpp: In function âset set_difference(const set&, const set&)â:
set.cpp:90: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions
set.cpp: In function âbool is_subset(const set&, const set&)â:
set.cpp:104: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions
set.cpp: In function âbool operator==(const set&, const set&)â:
set.cpp:118: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions
    set.cpp: In function âstd::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const set&)â:
set.cpp:131: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions
```

I am unsure of what these mean, and was wondering how one would go about fixing this.

Comment: so... what is your question?

Comment: which line is line no. 131?

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/207604/ this dude has very similar code to yours (down to the comments in the code), maybe you can ask them

Comment: My crystal ball tells me everywhere you use `int i` compared against `used` you run into this problem. That should be a strong hint one is signed, the other not. So.... fix it?

Comment: Hint: you don't need a signed number to index an array.

Comment: so many duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/q/859943/995714

Answer (score 2):

The warning you are getting is most likely coming from your for loops:

example:

```
void set::remove(const value_type& entry)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < used; i++) //the comparison in question is on this line
    {
       if(data[i] == entry)
       {
            data [i]  = data [used - 1];
            used --;
            return;
       }
    }
}
```

The statement: `i < used` is comparing `i` which is an `int` and `used` which I am assuming is of an unsigned type.

If you were to look at each line number specified in the warning I believe they would all correspond to the for loops in your functions.

The easiest way to fix these warnings would be to replace `int` with whatever type you are using for `used`.

For example if `used` were and `unsigned int` your for loops would become:

```
void set::remove(const value_type& entry)
{
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < used; i++) 
    {
        /*...*/
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your header file, I am assuming `used` is defined as an `unsigned int`. In your loops, you define `i` as an `int`, leading to your warnings.

Because a negative value in a signed integer evaluates to a large positive number in an unsigned integer, comparing the two can lead to unexpected results. The quick solution is to change all uses of `i` to `unsigned int` or whatever actual type is used for `used`.